# Minimum permissions to give to a project manager

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm new to Visual studio online. A project manager will join me for a project, and I want to give him full permissions to create/edit/manage processes, features, backlogs. I want also to deny his access to everything else ( Code, builds, tests... ).

What I have done :
- Created a group ( Project managers ) and added him in it.
- Added this group to project team
- Denied access to everything in "Version Control" tab

This way, the user can see the project, and can create features and backlogs, but not see code.

The problem is that, for a reason I can't figure out, the user can't see the items I have created before( features etc ), everything seems empty, he can only do it when I add his group to the group Project Administrators. I can't figure out what is the missing permission in Project Administrators ( or inherited one ) that I should give to his group.

Can someone help me please ?

NB: Maybe I don't have to create a new group and use one of the existing ones.

Comment: It's really not worth the effort! If you don't trust them not to go changing code and messing with your builds then don't have them on your project.

Comment: It's my wife, I have full trust in her, but not in some malware hacker who can get her password.

Comment: Why can't the malware hacker just get yours?

Comment: I would recommend that you use VSTS (TFS Online) and setup 2 factor auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the group has the permission to view/edit the work items via following steps:

1. Open your project from Web Portal.
2. Click "Manage Project" button in the up right corner.
3. Click "Areas" tab.
4. Right click on the root area and select "Security".
5. Add your group if it isn't listed in the dialog and make sure it has "View work items in this node" and "Edit work items in this node" permission at least.